# Developing and debugging Sencha apps without sencha's paid services

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I started working with sample sencha apps. I find it really hard to find typo and errors in my code.

I added the eclipse plugin for auto-complete during coding. Buts its a trial version just like the sencha architect. Am really confused on how the sencha app should be developed.

I want to know the tools that sencha developers are using so that I can deploy and debug effeciently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workflow / tools choice when developing an application is a subjective matter so I'm going to talk about my experience, having been a Sencha Touch developer for the last year.

> I find it really hard to find typo and errors in my code.
>   ...
>   Am really confused on how the sencha app should be developed.

This is not a matter of tools in my opinion. Sencha Touch has an unavoidable steep learning curve. You should start with simple examples, and you could ask here when you have *specific programming issues* (I personally found Sencha Touch forums less useful than stackoverflow).

The most important thing is understanding the basics concepts:

- Sencha Touch class system (http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-class-system),
- How Sencha implements MVC (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/controllers)
                          (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/views),
- Sencha Touch Layouts (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/layouts),
- Sencha Touch Components (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/components)

Also all of [these guides](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide) will be very useful, make sure you understand them and learn to use Sencha Docs, which definetely has some obscure, non explained properties, but should still be your main resource when developing a Sencha Touch app.

Debugging will always be tricky, unfortunately sometimes setting the wrong property on a Component, or misunderstanding how a Component is meant to work, ends up with some obscure `var is not defined` error. Do not fear to check Sencha Touch source code when this happens, code is well written and usually easy to understand.

Here the tools to use are again Sencha Touch Docs (when hovering on a class title you can examine directly its source code, plus your browser debugging console. Use frequent `console.debug()` messages, and when something weird happens inside framework classes stop execution with `debugger;` and step inside source code).

Now back to your question: I have been using the following tools:

- NetBeans,
- Chrome DevTools,
- Chrome Ripple Extension,
- Sencha Command (optional)
- Compass CSS authoring framework
- a couple shell scripts

The IDE is a matter of personal choice, Netbeans has some nice Javascript suggestions: it highlights variables when they are used but not defined in the current scope, or defined but not used, which really helps a lot against typos. It is very heavy in terms of memory usage. I guess Eclipse, or even a lighter one could be equally good.

Chrome is kinda a forced choice if you are on Windows, their DevTools are excellent, make sure you master them, they will be your main working tools. Once again: lot of RAM helps.

Ripple is an invaluable extension that allows you to test your mobile app on different devices and if you are using Phonegap for native deployment it emulates a part of its API on the browser.

Compass is the tool suggested by Sencha to compile their sass files. There is a detailed tutorial on how to setup compass on Sencha Docs.

I have been using Sencha Command but it's not strictly necessary, if you don't care about resources minification (but you should) you will not miss much about it. If you are developing a native app you can make up for the lack of Sencha Command deploy function with a simple shell script that copies html/js/css resources to the assets folder of your Phonegap project.

Another script activates automatically `compass watch` on the `/resources/sass` folder at startup, to avoid having to manually do that each time.

Just my two cents, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

[Anubis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068131/anubis) covered majority of the bee knees in hand coding Sencha Touch.

I'd like to add a couple more cents into the kitty.

My personal preference for IDE is Sublime Text. Searching through entire projects of code for anything, I've not seen an equal for effectiveness and speed. You can customise everything - especially colours and keybindings. It also has a ludicrous wealth of plugins, including working in correlation to Chrome, as well as Github.

## SENCHA GUIDES

[Miami Coder Tutorials](http://miamicoder.com/sencha-touch-tutorials/) - great collection of practical tutorials which will help you understand development patterns faster than most other guides. Great for starters.

[Figleaf Training](http://training.figleaf.com/tutorials/senchacomplete/index.cfm) can be a little unconventional, but a great free means of learning Sencha Touch and almost everything it is capable of. Great for starters too.

[Druck IT](http://druckit.wordpress.com/category/javascript/sencha-touch-2/) - solid collection of guides and ST information. Has links to many other useful sites such as these listed.

[Mitchell Simoens](http://mitchellsimoens.com/?cat=4) - Mitchell is Sencha staff, a quality coder, and his site has some great advice and snippets to help learn. This is where you'll truly learn how to code ST well. Helps towards getting a grasp, but mainly for mid+ knowledge.

[Ladysign](http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/category/sencha/sencha-touch/) - one of the Sencha Trainers. Has content that clears up "how to" in many facets other sites and books never even mention. Quality information. This info will get you above basic and flesh out your knowledge and understanding.

[Modus Create](http://moduscreate.com/) - Jay Garcia is one of the devs of ST. Modus Create is his enterprise, which contains some useful guides within the blog.

[Custom Font Icons](http://bruno.tavares.me/sencha-touch/adding-custom-font-icons-to-sencha-touch-2-2/) - complete guide for 2.2. Very useful.

There's a few other sites that were incredible sources of tidbits through to information on how to code ST professionally. These links above will help immensely though. **Above all, read the source code.** It is very well documented, as well as being an example in itself of how to use the code. I have learnt ludicrous amounts this way.

## GRUNT (with NPM/Node.js)!

Use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)! This will automate the vast majority of what you want to do. For example, typing "grunt" in the command line could jshint/jslint your code, concatenate all .js files together, all css files together (including all the compass joy), obfuscate, compress, run a comprehensive set of unit tests (especially Phantom), output to desired location, then add a cherry on top by refreshing your browser window. Add in the grunt watch plugin, and it'll do that every time a file is saved in defined directories. Any bugs in your code - you get accurate specific line numbers where it is broken.

The beauty of grunt is extended by optional alternate commandlines for different tasks. Also, you can specify in the package.json file of a few kB the precise list of plugins you wish to use with the gruntfile you've created, saving megabytes of file transfer. NPM can process that file, and download and install all that is required to operate. Makes for fast setup on another computer.

Side note: [Touch Node](https://www.npmjs.org/package/touch-node) has come of age. This permits all ST's class structure to develop your serverside javascript.

### Want to include Sencha Cmd?

Sencha Cmd (finally) does do a decent job of collecting only the dependent classes from the full library.

[grunt-sencha-build](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-sencha-build)

[grunt-senchacmd](https://github.com/jtrussell/grunt-senchacmd)

### Alternative for Sencha Cmd

Extend Grunt with [Matt Goldspink's grunt-sencha-dependencies](http://www.mattgoldspink.co.uk/2013/02/06/fed-up-sencha-cmd-want-to-use-grunt-with-ext-js-and-sencha-touch/) which works for both ST and ExtJS, or use [grunt-sencha-resolver](https://github.com/revolunet/grunt-sencha-resolver) - this latter one I haven't used.